Terminology: [strongly/weakly] locally P for topological properties P
Let $P_X(x)$ be a property ("$P$") of a point $x$ in a space $X$. There are several reasonable ways to define "locally $P$":

For every point $x\in X$ and open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists an open neighborhood $V\subseteq U$ of $x$ where $P_V(x)$ holds.
For every point $x\in X$ and neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists a neighborhood $V\subseteq U$ of $x$ where $P_V(x)$ holds.
For every point $x\in X$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ where $P_U(x)$ holds.

Sometimes these are equivalent, such as locally Hausdorff ($P_X(x)\equiv X$ Hausdorff). Sometimes these are only equivalent under certain extra assumptions: locally compact ($P_X(x)\equiv X$ compact) #2 & #3 are distinct, but coincide for regular spaces.
Has there been a careful study of when such properties are distinct? And is there any convention for the terminology of such properties? I typically use "weakly locally $P$" for #3, and "locally $P$" for #2, but I understand perhaps that "strongly locally contractible" might be more common for #1 while "locally contractible" sometimes means #3. (N.B. Geoffrey Sangton points out in the comments that Borsuk's definition of locally contactible can't be captured by $P_X(x)$...)

I suppose not, because locally contractable at a specific point is not a topological property; it's a property of a space and a specified point. But maybe I shouldn't be talking about subspace properties and allow properties of space, point pairs.

What is a "property of a point in a space"?
Or do you simply mean topological property? It seems that all you are talking of, is just a localization of topological property. For instance, in T2 spaces, locally compact is then just 3. for the topological property compact (i.e. for every point there is a neighborhood $U$, such that $U$ is $P$.)

I think there are more reasonable ways to localize a topological property, for instance $3^\prime$.: for every $x \in X$, there is an open neighborhood of $x$ which is $P$. Or: ...  there is an (open or not) neighborhood of $x$ such that its closure is $P$. Or the latter required to be contained in each neighborhood of $x$ etc.

I've deleted my original comment because it was incorrect in a subtle way, since the point being contracted to need not be $x$. The definition of locally contractible from Borsuk's Theory of Retracts is: A space  is said to be locally contractible at a point $x$ provided that each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a neighborhood $U_0$ such that the inclusion $U_0 \hookrightarrow U$ is homotopic to the constant map with value $x' \in U$; the error I made is tacitly assuming $x = x'$. And is locally contractible if it is locally contractible at each point. (The other version also appears.)
